# How to insert table view inside another view?

Tags: views

I have created a View and two display blocks inside the View and set the format to table on each.

like this:

[image: table look]

I will display these two tables at the front page. Now I need to write a common  for both tables

```
<div class="col-sm-12 table member">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-xl-7 member_payments">
        <!--table_1-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-xl-5 member_payments services">   
        <!--table_2-->
    </div>
</div>
```

For this may I need to use table view inside another view?

My tables looks like this
[image: table look]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put `services view block` reference into your `members view block` for example into Header / Footer. Then by overriding template for this view type `view-view--<views_machine_name>` you can easily add Bootstrap classes and wrap each table into specific container / wrapper.

In your main view click on button **Add** at Header section. Add **Rendered entity - block** and type in your second block block_machine_name *(it means your second block needs to be added to some region with specific machine name)*.